# Get boundary coordinates of the current user view ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Looking at the example:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/?sample=overview-map
The Overview map knows exactly the location of the user, and changes the grey square according to the movement, changing window size etc.

To do that, the geometry property of this shape get's the "extent" field of the viewMap:

```
watchUtils.init(mainView, "extent", (extent) => {
  extent3Dgraphic.geometry = extent;
})
```

the extent doesn't hold the coordinates of each point, but data such as:
 `width, height, xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax`.

Having this data, i'm looking to get the boundary coordinates of the user, something like this:

```
topRight: [latitude: -40.242, longitude: 75],
topLeft: [latitude: -50.242, longitude: 75],
bottomRight: [latitude: -40.242, longitude: 45],
bottomLeft: [latitude: -30.242, longitude: 45]
```

Is there any way to calculate this points by the given data of the 'extent'? Or any way to get the points by another function/property?